# error while using a javascript in angular project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular7

I am creating a side bar for my application using angular version 7. I wanted to include the java script with certain functions for this project. for that I followed the following steps

1. I created a js folder under the assets file and named it as SideBar.js
2. In the SideBar.js i wrote the piece of java script as shown below.

```js
function toggleSideBar() {
  document.getElementById("SideBar").classList.toggle('active');
}
```

3. I added the path of the Jquery to he scripts in the angular.json
4. In my sidebar.component.ts file inside the ngonInit() I declared the function as shown below.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-bar',
  templateUrl: './side-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-bar.component.scss']
})


export class SideBarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    (function (toggleSideBar) {
      toggleSideBar('.toggleSideBar').toggleSideBar();
    })(jQuery);
  }
}
```

i am not sure what is going wrong. I am still not able to toggle the side bar i created. any lead would be helpful.

EDIT: adding the side component .html

```
<nav>
  <div id="SideBar">
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSideBar()">
    <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

code: Sidebar.component.scss

```
nav {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 #SideBar {
   position: fixed;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100%;
   background: #151719;
   left: -200px;
 }
#SideBar ul li {
  color: rgba(230,230,230,0.9);
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
}
#SideBar .active{
  left: 0px;
}
#SideBar .toggle-btn{
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px;
  top:20px;
}
  #SideBar .toggle-btn span{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #151719;
    margin: 5px 0px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using jQuery code, you can do the same thing using only Angular.
I don't see the need to include the JS function in the component class file.

Comment: @NiralMunjariya means ? how can i do it in angular?? do you mean using the material package?

Comment: When you want to toggle the siderbar, meaning when the toggle event will be fired?

Comment: Why not use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) since you're just toggling a class?

Comment: @NiralMunjariya when i click on the icon , then the side bar should open. when i click else where it should close.

Comment: @ColbyHunter can you provide a example  ?

Comment: @ColbyHunter I am using scss styling

Comment: Can you add the HTML code for the same (side-bar.component.html) ?

Comment: @NiralMunjariya yeah sure

Comment: @NiralMunjariya I have added the html and scss content

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1mvluu) is much simpler than using jQuery and in some ways "purer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using Native JS click event, just use Angular click event as below and add/remove class using the flag.

sidebar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-bar',
  templateUrl: './side-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-bar.component.scss']
})


export class SideBarComponent implements OnInit {

  open: boolean = true;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {  }
}
```

sidebar.component.html

```
<nav>
  <div id="SideBar" [ngClass]="{'active': open}">
    <div class="toggle-btn" (click)="open = !open">
    <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: For some reason, stil I am facing the issue

Comment: Can you please mention what's the issue?

Comment: I have an hamburger menu in my page. And when I click on it I should be able to see my side bar . But when I click on it. it doesnt respond.

Comment: I am not able to see the list that I have mentioned.

Comment: There was an issue with your Style. check the live demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thzca2)

Comment: Glad to know that, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

#### The Problem with jQuery and Angular

First off, this is not meant to be read as "Never use jQuery and Angular together". jQuery has some legitimate uses when working with Angular, but **most things can be handled in pure Angular alone**. Angular is meant to handle the DOM, from the creation and manipulation of components/elements to even DOM Events.

#### Using [ngClass] instead

`ngClass` has multiple ways of manipulating which classes get added to your element which you can find [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description). One key thing to get from this is that while `ngClass` can be declared with `string, string[], Set<string>`, once they are delcared they cannot be removed. Which is why we have the abilty to use `{[klass: string]: expression}`. Let's look at an example:

*app.component.html*

```
<p [ngClass]="{'active': toggle}">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<button (click)="toggle = !toggle">Toggle</button>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
export class AppComponent  {
  toggle: boolean = true
}
```

Instead of using `onclick` we use `(click)` which is Angular's way of handling the DOM Events. And instead of using `document.getElementById("SideBar").classList.toggle('active');` we use a component property (`toggle`) that is being manipulated by the click event: `(click)="toggle = !toggle"`.

The magic happens in `[ngClass]="{'active': toggle}"` which is saying "If toggle is true, then add the class `active`". I have a StackBlitz example of this code which can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1mvluu).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.